# Simulador de caixa eletrônico no Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, android-layout

Estou montando um simulador básico de caixa eletrônico no Android Studio, onde o usuário deve digitar a senha, que já está pré-definida, no caso é "Java". Caso a senha esteja certa, aparece a mensagem "Senha Correta", se estiver errada, aparece a mensagem "Senha Incorreta" na tela. Se o usuário errar 3 vezes a senha, aparecerá uma mensagem "Cartão Bloqueado", e é basicamente isso. Mas com meu código, quando a senha está correta, a mensagem aparece certa, já se a senha está errada ele apenas mostra "Cartão Bloqueado", sem passar pela mensagem "Senha Incorreta", queria saber se fiz algo de errado.
Segue o código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText digito;
TextView res;
Button entrar;
int cont = 0;
String senha = "Java";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    digito = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    entrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEntrar);
    res = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);
}

public void Verificacao(View view) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (digito.getText().toString().equals(senha)) {
            res.setText("Senha Correta");
            break;

        }else if (i == 3) {
            res.setText("Cartão Bloqueado");
            break;

        } else {
            res.setText("Senha Incorreta");

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que quando você clica no botão você chama o método `Verificacao`. Quando esse método é chamado, ele verifica 4 vezes (está dentro de um `for`) para `i = 0`, `1`, `2` e `3`.

Para alcançar o comportamento correto, você deve contar numa variável externa ao método:

```
int tentativa = 0;

public void Verificacao(View view) {
    if (digito.getText().toString().equals(senha)) {
        res.setText("Senha Correta");
    } else if (tentativa == 3) {
        res.setText("Cartão Bloqueado");
    } else {
        tentativa++; // Na primeira chamada, tentativa = 1
        res.setText("Senha Incorreta");
    }
}
```

Desse jeito, caso o usuário erre na terceira vez em diante, aparecerá a mensagem "Cartão Bloqueado". Isso acontece porque passei a começar a partir de 1 ao invés de 0, como no seu `for`, e porque estou somando somente quando ele erra e o cartão não está bloqueado.

**Dica:** Não é uma boa prática um método começar com uma letra maiúscula, recomendo renomeá-lo para `verificacao` ou até mesmo para `verificarSenha`, que torna mais explícito o que ele verifica.

**Observação:** Parti do pressuposto de que a sua função `Verificacao` está sendo chamada uma vez quando o usuário clica no botão. Não é possível dizer se isso  realmente acontece ou não com base no código que você compartilhou (imagino que você tenha colocado no XML).
Caso deseje atrelar um `onClick` ao botão na criação da `Activity` (no código Java):

```
entrar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        verificacao(v)
    } 
});
```

Comment: Eu referenciei o próprio método na propriedade onClick do XML. 
E eu acabei de testar sua ideia e deu certo, só que o comportamento não ficou como eu queria, então coloquei o tentativas++ dentro do else e não dentro do if, e funcionou corretamente. 
E sua dica sobre o método em letra maiúscula começarei a ter este hábito.

Comment: De fato, o `tentativas++` estava no local errado. Já editei na resposta. Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 